# overriding equals operator

Tags: c#

I am trying to override Equals so that it compares based on a variable ID:

```
public class OrderID
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    public OrderID(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is OrderID)
        {
            return ((OrderID)obj).ID == ID;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

However when I test this in the following manner it returns false:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    OrderID i1 = new OrderID("Hello");
    OrderID i2 = new OrderID("Hello");

    bool test = i1 == i2;

    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

What is the problem? When I try to step through it, my override is not even stepped into.

Comment: is using the == operator the same thing as calling i1.Equals(i2); I would have said no but you learn something new everyday...

Comment: @Rob they are not the same, that is the problem. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An object's Equals() method is not that same as the '==' operator. You will need to overload the '==' operator on your type, or call `i1.Equals(i2)` instead of `i1 == i2`.

[MSDN Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`operator ==` will only by default tell you if both`i1` and `i2` point to the same object (which they don't).  `operator ==` can be overridden but it is only recommended for immutable types.

What you want is:

```
bool test = i1.Equals(i2);
```

And use `.Equals` ID not `operator ==` ID

```
if (obj is OrderID)
{
  return ((OrderID)obj).ID.Equals(ID);
}
```

To check for reference equality use `ReferenceEquals`. To check for value equality, use `Equals`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned use `i1.Equals(i2)` to compare -  In addition also remember that you have to override `GetHashCode()` when overriding Equals, otherwise your class might not work as expected.